# SQL query for summary of change between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have two tables `EmployeeA` and `EmployeeB` that contain employee info. Both have the same columns like Guid, FullName, Age, Salary, and Address. both the tables have many records, and each employee has max 1 record in each table.

`EmployeeA` is kind of original table and data can't be changed. so its a read only where data into the `EmployeeA` gets imported from API.

Initially the data in `EmployeeB` table comes from the `EmployeeA` table through UI and user can modify it from UI. So `EmployeeB` can have modified data.

I need a result of change for only those columns which are modified in `EmployeeB` table.

Example :

```
Column Name    EmployeeA's Data  EMployeeB's Data
--------------------------------------------------
Salary         $98000            $110000
Address        ABC, USA          PQR, USA
```

*(There are no changes in FullName and Age columns)*.

What could a query look like to return the above result set?

Comment: Are all columns ***really*** the same datatype? I ask because age should not be stored in a string column, and you shouldn't coerce integers, dates, etc, in to strings just so you can output them in the same column. Much better would be to have 1 row per employee, and then ***all*** the columns from each source table (aliased to have different column names). Why do you think you need to pivot to multiple rows per employee?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join both table and compare the value from both the tables. Use `APPLY` to pivot it

```
select a.GUID, c.ColumnName, c.EmpA, c.EmpB
from   EmployeeA a
       inner join EmployeeB b on a.GUID = b.GUID
       cross apply
       (
           select ColumnName = 'FullName', 
                  EmpA = a.FullName, 
                  EmpB = b.FullName
           where  a.FullName <> b.FullName

           union all

           select ColumnName = 'Age', 
                  EmpA = convert(varchar(100), a.Age), 
                  EmpB = convert(varchar(100), b.Age)
           where  a.Age <> b.Age

           union all

           select ColumnName = 'Salary', 
                  EmpA = convert(varchar(100), a.Salary), 
                  EmpB = convert(varchar(100), b.Salary)
           where  a.Salary <> b.Salary

           union all

           select ColumnName = 'Address', 
                  EmpA = a.Address, EmpB = b.Address
           where  a.Address <> b.Address
       ) c
```

Note : you might want to change above query to handle null value

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT a.whatever EXCEPT SELECT b.whatever)` will deal with nulls also. `varchar(10)` feels a little small

Answer (score -1):

There are no sample data, but it could be something like:

```
WITH 
    A AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ID", 'NAME 1' "NAME", 100 "SALARY", 'ABC' "ADDRESS", 24 "AGE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ID", 'NAME 2' "NAME", 200 "SALARY", 'DEF' "ADDRESS", 30 "AGE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "ID", 'NAME 3' "NAME", 300 "SALARY", 'GEH' "ADDRESS", 32 "AGE" FROM DUAL 
        ),
    B AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ID", 'NAME 1' "NAME", 100 "SALARY", 'ABC' "ADDRESS", 24 "AGE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 "ID", 'NAME 2' "NAME", 220 "SALARY", 'DEF, DEF' "ADDRESS", 30 "AGE" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3 "ID", 'NAME 3' "NAME", 330 "SALARY", 'GEH' "ADDRESS", 32 "AGE" FROM DUAL 
        )
    
    SELECT
        A.NAME "NAME", 'SALARY' "COLUMN_NAME", To_Char(A.SALARY) "A_DATA", To_Char(B.SALARY) "B_DATA"
    FROM
        A
    INNER JOIN
        B ON(A.ID = B.ID)
    WHERE
        A.SALARY <> B.SALARY
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        A.NAME "NAME", 'ADDRESS' "COLUMN_NAME", A.ADDRESS "A_DATA", B.ADDRESS "B_DATA"
    FROM
        A
    INNER JOIN
        B ON(A.ID = B.ID)
    WHERE
        A.ADDRESS <> B.ADDRESS
  ORDER BY 1
-- 
-- Result
-- NAME     COLUMN  A_DATA  B_DATA
-- NAME 2   SALARY  200     220
-- NAME 2   ADDRESS DEF     DEF, DEF
-- NAME 3   SALARY  300     330
```

Comment: This is a MS SQL Server question, but this syntax is Oracle.

Comment: Sorry, I see it now. If the logic is ok to you just adjust it to SQL Server sintax. Regards...